# What's the difference between Persona4 and Persona4 the Golden?

Tags: persona4

Is **Persona4 the Golden ANIMATION** simply a remake of **Persona4 the ANIMATION**? Or are the stories actually different?

It looks like the Golden is an improved remake of the Persona4 game for the Playstation Vita, but after seeing the first episode of the Golden ANIMATION, it doesn't seem to be much different at all from the original anime.

Comment: The second episode actually skipped a bunch of plot points that the series covered. You can see the calendar skip way ahead in episode 2. Any additional differences for the animation will have to wait until the series gets a few more episodes released.

Comment: P4GA dialogue really based in game choice, the former P4A not, AFAIK. And also Marie route, will be big part of story.

Answer (score 4):

Based on what I've watched, seen comments on and and search about, P4 Golden Animation is based on the route oriented around Marie in the P4 Golden Animation video game. The anime will retell the original P4 story, however with bonus events with Marie, rather than following the original plot of the P4 anime.

Description from [Anime Ultima](http://www.animeultima.tv/watch/Persona-4-The-Golden-Animation-english-subbed-dubbed-online/):

> Adaptation of Persona 4's remake video game, Persona 4 The Golden. The story retells the events of the original while featuring a new character, Marie.